# openapi-generator for java is not able to generate class for oneOf field with primitive objects

Tags: java, yaml, openapi, openapi-generator

I have add the below property in my yaml file:

```yaml
fieldValue:
    oneOf:
      - type: string
      - type: integer
```

Swagger-codegen version

```
       <plugin>
          <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
          <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>4.1.1</version>
       </plugin>
```

CustomClass.java class is created with the field

```
public static final String SERIALIZED_NAME_FIELD_VALUE = "fieldValue";
@SerializedName(SERIALIZED_NAME_FIELD_VALUE)
private OneOfstringinteger fieldValue = null;
```

But getting this error

```
/Users/....../CustomClass.java:[23,41] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol: class OneOfstringinteger
```

Is there a way to generate OneOfstringinteger class?

I tried with objects also but same error came:

```yaml
fieldValue:
    oneOf:
      - $ref: '#/definitions/StringValue'
      - $ref: '#/definitions/NumberValue'

definitions:
  StringValue:
    type: object
    properties:
      name:
        type: string

  NumberValue:
    type: object
    properties:
      name:
        type: number
```

```
cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class OneOfStringValueNumberValue
```